# dropdown list selected item loads listview vb asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a search function which loads a list view using sql.

What I would like is for the user to be able to search by say "name" then a dropdown list will populate with all the department names who have that users searched name in. Then click on the item in the dropdown list to then populate a listview.

Here is what I have so far

drop down

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"   DataTextField="DepartmentName" DataValueField="DepartmentName">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>




<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnectionConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [DepartmentName], [ExtensionName], [Surname], [jobTitle], [FirstName], [Pager] FROM [UserInformation]" FilterExpression="DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' or FirstName + ' ' + Surname LIKE '%{0}%' or FirstName + ' ' + DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' or Surname + ' ' + DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' or FirstName + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' or
                                FirstName + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + ExtensionName LIKE '%{0}%' or DepartmentName + ' ' + ExtensionName LIKE '%{0}%' or ExtensionName + ' ' + DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' or ExtensionName + ' ' + FirstName LIKE '%{0}%' or FirstName + ' ' + ExtensionName LIKE '%{0}%' or ExtensionName LIKE '%{0}%' or jobTitle LIKE '%{0}%' or Pager LIKE '%{0}%' or DepartmentName LIKE '{0}'">
                                <FilterParameters>


                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="DepartmentName" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ExtensionName" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Surname" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="JobTitle" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="FirstName" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Pager" ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="DepartmentName" ControlID="DropDownList1"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />

                                </FilterParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think this is the FilterExpression you're looking for:

```
DepartmentName LIKE '%{0}%' OR
ExtensionName LIKE '%{1}%' OR
Surname LIKE '%{2}%' OR
JobTitle LIKE '%{3}%' OR
FirstName LIKE '%{4}%' OR
Pager LIKE '%{5}%' OR
DepartmentName LIKE '%{6}%'
```

You don't really need to concatenate those combinations when you're searching `'%string%'`.

For example:
if `DepartmentName` is 'Office', then `FirstName + ' ' + DepartmentName` might be 'Bob Office' and both would return the same rows when searching for 'Office' in the `DepartmentName` dropdown/textbox. So I simplified your FilterExpression and then I changed the indexes (`{0}`)  to match the corresponding ControlParameters.

**EDIT**

Here's one way to do what you've asked for...

**ASPX**:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" Height="27px" OnTextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged" />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="DepartmentSource" DataTextField="DepartmentName" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DepartmentSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnectionConnectionString  %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [UserInformation] WHERE ([DepartmentName] LIKE '%' + @SearchParam+ '%') ORDER BY [DepartmentName]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="SearchBox" Name="SearchParam" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**CS**:

```
protected void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DepartmentDDL.DataBind();
}
```

You could add a button to tie an event to instead of the `SearchBox_TextChanged` event (hit enter in the textbox to trigger it by the way).If you're looking for something that filters while you're typing, you'll need to play around with this a bit more or take a different approach.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to type in a search bar using "name" then a dropdown list will populate with all the departments that have that name in. thanks

Comment: also there is only one textbox on this web form txtSearch1. I thought this would mean all the indexes needed to be '%{0}%'.

Comment: Ya somehow I missed that they were all bound to txtSearch1, but now that I understand what you're looking for I don't think you'll need any of those.